How to design a strategy to let a robot jump through $n$ boxes after exponential jumping?
More specificly, I have an array of $n$ boxes and a robot initially in the first box. In each time, the robot can jump ahead (+1), stay in (0), and jump back (-1). The robot's action stops when it jumps into the last box. I want to design a strategy such that for every $2^{n-1}\leq k \leq 2^n-1$, the possibility that the robot jumps into the last box after $k$ steps is positive, and in the worst case the robot stops after $O(exp(n))$ steps.
Actually it is related to control the tape head of a turing machine. This problem remind me of random walk, however, it may take infinite steps to rich the last box.

If you let the robot jump randomly to the left or right each with probability $1/4$ and let it stay at it's place with probability $1/2$, then the probability that in $k$ steps it reaches the last box is always positive, since $n\le 2^{n-1}\le k$ for $n\ge 1$ (the probability is positive because there is always a path for it to reach the last box, and enough steps to execute said path). Does this help you?

Welcome to MSE! See this link on how to ask a good question. Kindly edit the question to include appropriate details like the source of the question or what you have tried to solve it. Then, other users will be more likely to help you. Otherwise, your post can attract downvotes and close votes.

You could have some arbitrary rule for the three possible steps all with positive probability except that (a) there is no jumping back from the initial box and (b) something like if after $k$ steps the box position is lower than $\log_e(k)$ then the next step is a jump forward.

@HackR Well. The problem is, it is likely to take arbitrary long time to get to the last box, and I want to avoid this case.

Does your strategy need to be memoryless? If not you can define your strategy such that it behave randomly at first (during exp(n) steps) and then jump ahead to ensure to reach the final box in exp(n)+n at most jumps.

What are the restrictions on the strategy? I can't think of why it cannot be done straightforwardly without any restriction.

Let the robot jump ahead at $i$-th step ($1$-based) with probability $\frac{1}{2^{\ell + 1} - i}$ if he is in the box $\ell$, where $2^{\ell} \le i < 2^{\ell + 1}$, or stay otherwise. Then without a priori knowing value of $n > 1$ he will jump into box $n$ at step $\xi \sim U\{2^{n - 1}, 2^{n} - 1\}$. (For $n = 1$ the robot is initially in the box $n$, so jumping there after $2^{n - 1} = 2^{n} - 1 = 1$ step is impossible.)
Indeed for $i = 2^{\ell} + t$ the robot is initially in box $\ell$ with probability $\frac{t}{2^{\ell}}$ or in box $\ell + 1$ with probability $\frac{2^{\ell} - t}{2^{\ell}}$. Being in the box $\ell$ he jumps with probability $\frac{1}{2^{\ell} - t}$ into the box $\ell + 1$. Note that the probability is $1$ for $i = 2^{\ell + 1} - 1$, that's why robot is definitely in the box $\ell + 1$ after $2^{\ell} - 1$ steps. So the probability that he will jump into box $\ell + 1$ at step $i$ is $\frac{1}{2^{\ell}}$ for all $i = 2^{\ell}, 2^{\ell} + 1, \ldots, 2^{\ell + 1} - 1$.
